# Check if element exist or not

Tags: c++, data-structures

I have a multimap.

```
std::multimap<CString, CString> NameInsituteMap;
```

and I have to write function which return true if both name and institute matches otherwise false;

```
bool InsituteExist( const CString Name, const CString Insitute )
{

}
```

I can find the key and iterate all the value to compare if Institute exist or not.

I want to know if there is any direct way of doing that instead of looping through all the element and comparing.

I am open to use any other data structure than multimap if that makes things nicer.

Comment: @BenVoigt Well, the OP says "if Institute exist for the given name", which is kind of ambiguous. It's not clear whether both name and value are supposed to match.

Comment: It sounds like you want something more like

   `std::map<string, std::set<string>>`

instead of `multimap`.

(where `string` can be `CString`, `std::string`, etc)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - Yes both name and value should match.

Comment: It depends a little on how large your set is and how long your strings are and if you need the ordering, but I’d suggest using an `unordered_set<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> ` container for which you would have to create a hash function in `std` but it works [out of the box](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c5d0b65c1fddda97) in `boost`. (Unordered associative containers have better complexity guarantees)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the sequence elements from the multimap for a given key efficiently. There is no better way to find a particular value from this sequence, than linear search.

`std::map<CString, std::set<CString>>` would be an alternative data structure, which is also efficient for finding whether a value exists in the set associated with the key. It has a bit different interface though. Instead of simply inserting a value to a key, you must "get" the value set of a key, insert into that set.

If the map aspect of your data structure isn't used otherwise, another simpler alternative is to use `std::set<std::pair<CString, Cstring>>`. This can be easily used to test if the key-value pair is in the set, but of course lacks other features that the multimap had.

Comment: Thanks, Using std::set<std::pair<CString, Cstring>> made my code really simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`equal_range`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/equal_range/) from `multimap`.

Here you have a [live example](http://cpp.sh/5qajq)

Comment: Thanks for the code, I decided to with std::set<std::pair<CString, Cstring>>  .